# XPath to href attribute & WriteLine the URL

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I understand there are many XPath href questions, but none suit my case or I am a beginner of it and don't know what's wrong with my code. Kindly bear with me if this is silly question.

I have this HTML structure:

```
<td valign="top">08-Jan-14 16:02</td>
<td valign="top"><span style="cursor:help;" title="Regulatory News Service">RNS</span></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="share-regulatory-news.asp?shareprice=BARC&amp;ArticleCode=d6rr2uxo&amp;ArticleHeadline=Blocklisting_Interim_Review" class="linkStoryHeadline rnsArticle" title="Blocklisting Interim Review">Blocklisting Interim Review</a></td>
<td valign="top">Company Announcement - General</td>
```

My code is:

```
HtmlNodeCollection cols5 = rows[i].SelectNodes(".//td[3]/a[@href]");
```

Stream writer to write the URL:

```
sw.WriteLine(cols5[j].InnerText);
```

The result appears to be `Blocklisting Interim Review` instead of the URL. Can anyone kindly look into it? I've went through XPath guide and search all over but still can't get the exact answer for my case. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what if you will add @href in the end? .//td[3]/a[@href]/@href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select attribute with XPath. Select `a` element and then get it's `href` attribute. Following xpath selects from third table cell `a` element which *has* `href` attribute (yes, predicate just specifies that attribute should exist, it does not selects attribute):

```
var a = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//td[3]/a[@href]");
var href = a.Attributes["href"].Value;
```

Returns

> share-regulatory-news.asp?shareprice=BARC&ArticleCode=d6rr2uxo&ArticleHeadline=Blocklisting_Interim_Review

Comment: Hi Sergey, thank you for guiding me. But I have no idea how to edit my code to what you said? Do you mind looking at it https://pastebin.com/X1J4uV72? I've been spending hours checking on this yet learnt nothing. :/

Comment: @Shyuan don't use `InnerText` of selected node. That will return inner text of `a` element, which is *"Blocklisting Interim Review"*. For `cols5` get attribute value, as I have shown

Comment: Can I ask you a silly question? Where do I put the above code? :(

Comment: @Shyuan I already answered it, use that code for `col5`

Comment: Is this what you mean? `cols5[j].Attributes["href"].Value`? :)

Comment: @Shyuan actually I didn't get why you have loop for columns there. It looks to me that you should use `SelectSingleNode` instead of `SelectNodes` and inner loop will not be needed. But yes, your last attempt should work (you can also check if `cols5[j]` is not null)

Comment: I am using loop because I have different files to go through, but with same format. :) I hope this makes sense?